# Could someone help me identify this Japanese brush-like font from the Boku no Hero Academia anime?

Tags: font-identification, japanese

I've tried to identify it on several webs like WhatFontIs, WhatTheFont, FontSquirrel and in a Japanese font identifier like en.likefont.com but they cannot recognize the font. That's why I need help with this.

This is what it says: 動地震伝
[image: 動地震伝]

This is what it says: 深淵闇躯
[image: 深淵闇躯]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello CacoLyoko 99, welcome to GD.SE! We have some [requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information. If you have any questions about this site, have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the help, those should help you get up to speed. Keep contributing and have fun here!

Comment: As with all lettering like this, keep the possibility into account that it isn't a font, but hand-painted. Both of them look rather consistent, but that could just be the sign of a very experienced calligraphist.

Comment: I'm not sure it's hand-painted. I'm going to upload another picture where there are two more Japanese characters with the same "font" but with another color and with a stroke. Tell me if I'm wrong please. Thank you so much for answering, by the way.